# Explicit solution of a free boundary problem for heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, heat-equation, variational-inequalities

Consider the free boundary problem

$$
\min\{u_t - u_{xx} -1, u \} = 0  \qquad \text{ in } (0,T)\times (-1,1) \\
u(0,\cdot) = 0  \qquad \text{ in } (-1,1)\\
u(\cdot, -1) = u(\cdot, 1) = 0  \qquad \text{ in } (0,T)
$$

Can we obtain an explicit solution for it?

Answer (score 7):

From the maximum principle, the solution $v$ of
$$v_t=v_{xx}+1,$$
together with the data $v=0$ at the boundary and initial time, is positive. Therefore your $u$ is nothing but $v$. It turns out that it can be expressed explicitly, using the heat kernel.